# symfony2 generate static html with twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there a way to put the html code from a twig template into a html file.
I mean, in this case

```
$html = $this->render('SiteBundle:Generated:home_news.html.twig', array('news' => $news))->getContent();
```

Is there a way where I can do this?

```
$html->output($html_file);
```

And it gerenates a html file with the template.

I'm doing this because I have news from a wordpress blog and I want to show the latest news in the homepage. So I would want to put the news of my site in a static file to avoid to generate it with each home request.

Answer (score 7):

If you check documentation more carefully, you'd find [this chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#creating-static-pages), which says:

```
$content = $this->renderView('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but sorry, I guess you haven't understand me. I dont want to show the output of the twig template. I'd want to keep this content into a html file, which I'll use in other places.

Comment: So `file_put_contents()` your `$content` - no? :)

Comment: yes, but I am asking about a way to do it with twig or with S2

Comment: There's no way to render directly to a file. Getting the render output as a string and using `file_put_contents()` on it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

To complete the @VitalityZurian answer:

First, generate your markup :

```
$content = $this->renderView('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
```

Then, write in file :

```
$file = file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

You can use Symfony2 help methods to deal with locations in your bundles:

```
$bundleResourcesDir = $this->get('kernel')->locateResource('@AcmeAnotherBundle/Resources/views');
file_put_contents($bundleResourcesDir.'/index.html.twig`
```

And retrieve it:

```
$view = $this->get('kernel')->locateResource('@AcmeAnotherBundle/Resources/views/index.html.twig');
```